# strange behaviour of maple when computing a sum with modulo

Tags: maple

I have defined a simple function:

```
c(n) = 2 * floor((n mod 24) / 12)
```

I want to compute the sum c(0) + c(1) + ... + c(n) with Maple, but the sums Maple computes are wrong. Here is a screenshot of an example showing an obviously wrong sum: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpmB2.png

I don't know what i am missing here ...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of problem is known as premature evaluation. What happens is that `sum` uses Maple's usual evaluation model, which includes evaluating arguments of procedure calls before actually doing the computation in the procedure body.

Look in particular at the result below of simply invoking `creneau(i)`. That result is what `sum` is seeing as its argument in your example. In other words, the `mod` operation has occurred prematurely, because the call to `creneau(i)` has evaluated prematurely.

```
creneau := n -> (2*floor((n mod 24)/12)):

creneau(38);

                           2

oops := creneau(i);

                            /1   \
                     2 floor|-- i|
                            \12  /

eval(oops, i=38);

                           6


add(oops, i=38..38);

                           6

sum(oops, i=38..38);

                           6

sum(creneau(i), i=38..38);

                           6

sum('creneau(i)', i=38..38);

                           2

add(creneau(i), i=38..38);

                           2
```

The usual way to fix this is to either use `add` instead of `sum` (since `add` has so-called "special evaluation rules") or to wrap the first argument to `sum` with so-called unevaluation- or delay-quotes.

What is unfortunate is that in 2D Math input mode the pretty-printed (Sigma) summation symbol looks the same for both `sum` and `add`. This makes this mistake all the harder to detect.

I would even guess that you had inserted the 2D Math summation from the Maple's Standard GUI's "Expression" palette, which unfortunately has `sum` but not `add` leading to more new user mistakes of this sort.

See also the help-page on [special evaluation rules](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=spec_eval_rules).

acer

Comment: "I would even guess that you had inserted the 2D Math summation from the Maple's Standard GUI's "Expression" palette" => yes.

Thank you so much for your answer !!